# Efficiently execute a method multiple times with arguments of each execution contained in an iterable

Tags: python, loops, list-comprehension

I have a method that I need to execute multiple times and then read a final result. The object looks like this:

```
class BlackBox(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self._x = 0

  def do_unknown_caulculation(self, word):
    self._x += len(word)

  def get_result(self):
    return self._x
```

I thought of two ways of doing the task. In a loop and by using a list comprehension:

```
def loopit(words, aggregator):
  for word in words:
    aggregator.do_unknown_caulculation(word)
  return aggregator.get_result()


def comprehendit(words, aggregator):
  [aggregator.do_unknown_caulculation(word) for word in words]
  return aggregator.get_result()


words = ['I', 'need', 'to', 'aggregate', 'this']

print (loopit(words, BlackBox()), comprehendit(words, BlackBox()))
```

I found the list comprehension version to be slightly faster but I am not convinced it's a right way to do it. It seems that I am misusing the intended functionality and I do not know if it's even safe to do that from thread safety point of view.

What is the efficient and pythonic way of doing what I want here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would choose `loopit()` because `comprehendit()` builds a list of potentially many references to the None object that we don't need. I don't think there is always a *more pythonic* way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

you can use map in Python 3.x or imap in Python 2.7.x (in that case you have to import `from itertools import imap`)-

`def usingMap(words, aggregator):
  list(map(aggregator.do_unknown_caulculation, words))
  return aggregator.get_result()`

Comment: Why use `imap` if you then turn it into a `list` anyway? Also, this is no better (or really much different) then the list comprehension.